# Node Express redirect does not redirect the initial visit, but redirects everything else (F5, links)

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, https

I am trying to force redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, and have almost succeeded.
Following other SO posts, I have this code :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') === 'http' && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        console.log("redirecting to https : " + req.url);
        res.redirect(301, 'https://' + 'website.com' + req.url);
        return
    }
    next();
});
```

Everything gets redirected properly, EXCEPT the original hit, so when the client types 'website.com' in the browser bar, he is not redirected to HTTPS.
I haven't been able to find why that happens.

Comment: To debug if this is a browser or a server issue, use a tool like `cURL` to see if the server issues the redirect properly. You need to make sure that the route that serves the homepage is declared _after_ the middleware that redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: @robertklep Using curl, all 4 versions of the URL return 200. It seems to be an issue with the URL redirect of my provider.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound right.

Comment: @robertklep I managed to force HTTPS using a node module called SSLIFY. Now the only thing that doesn't work is combining google analytics traffic from naked subdomain and 'www'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to force HTTPS redirect simply using this module : https://github.com/florianheinemann/express-sslify